# Basic while loop returning a numbered list

Tags: python, list, function, while-loop

I'm very new to programming and am stuck on this basic question in one of my course quizzes: Write a function `numbered_list(items)` that prints a numbered (starting from 1) list of the items in the list `items` as shown in the test cases below. We are not allowed to use 'for' statements and it MUST have a `while` statement! I have tried using enumerate but I think my course is asking for a longer format

The closest I've gotten to is the code below, however still can't get the answer I want.

```
def numbered_list(items):
"""Prints a numbered list of items starting from 1"""
i = 0 
while i <len(items):
    print(items[i])
    i += 1
print (items)
```

Using the following test:

```
todos = ["Watch lecture videos", "Complete quiz", "Practise"]
numbered_list(todos)
```

It should result in:

```
1 Watch lecture videos
2 Complete quiz
3 Practise
```

Any help or answers would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You're only printing the item in position `i` in `items`. Print the index _and_ the item! You already have the index in `i` and the item in `items[i]`.

Comment: Instead of tracking `i` yourself, have you considered using [the `enumerate` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to do the counting for you?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy not allowed to use that function!

Comment: @crcvd hey I've tried print (items[i]) but it says list out of range

Comment: fwiw, it would not be idiomatic Python to use a while loop here. Rather you'd want a for loop or more probably a list comprehension. Also, using format strings to print make your code a lot more readable: `print(f"{idx}: {item}")` when `idx` and `item` are defined as the list number and the item at that location, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code changed to do exactly what you want :

```
def numbered_list(items):
    """Prints a numbered list of items starting from 1"""
    i = 0 
    while i <len(items):
        print(i+1,items[i])
        i += 1
    print (items)

todos = ["Watch lecture videos", "Complete quiz", "Practise"]
numbered_list(todos)
```

All i changed is the print statement, to print i+1 before the item of the list :

```
print(i+1,items[i])
```

This code outputs :

```
1 Watch lecture videos
2 Complete quiz
3 Practise
```

Comment: Thank you!! Much more straight forward now that I see it cheers

Comment: @coschal if this solved your problem, mark it as a solution and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate()` returns a pair of index and value.

```py
todos = ["Watch lecture videos", "Complete quiz", "Practise"]


def numbered_list(items):
    for idx, item in enumerate(items, start=1):
        print(idx, item)

numbered_list(todos)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code must be indented after the function definition
and after the `while` loop it must be like:

```
def numbered_list(items):
    """Prints a numbered list of items starting from 1"""
    i = 0 

    while i <len(items):
        print(items[i])
        
        
        i += 1
        
todos = ["Watch lecture videos", "Complete quiz", "Practise"]
numbered_list(todos)
```